# Como impedir que função modifique variável global?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Criando uma função para retornar um determinado valor, a partir de parâmetros recebidos, ela modifica a variável que recebe.

Por exemplo:

```js
var a = ["oi", "tchau"];

function duplicar(c) {
  var b = c;
  b[0] = b[0] + b[0];
  b[1] = b[1] + b[1];
  b = b.join(" ")
  return b
}
console.log('Variável antes da função: "' + a + '"')
console.log('Retorno da função: "' + duplicar(a) + '"')
console.log('Variável após função: "' + a + '" (não quero que isso aconteça)')
```

Não foi essa função que criei no meu código, mas está acontecendo a mesma coisa.
Sou bastante iniciante em JavaScript, não sei porque isso ocorre nem como impedir.

Quero que a função retorne um valor, modificando a variável a apenas dentro dela, sem modificar a variável a no escopo de origem.

Já tentei usando let, const, objetos...

Comment: O problema está provavelmente por que você não declarou a variavel B dentro da funçao. Sendo assim, o parametro que ela está recebendo é o A, e subistuindo a váriavel b por a.
Ficou claro?

Answer (score 2):

O parametro C estava recebendo o array A, e estava sobrescrevendo o mesmo.

```
var a = ["oi","tchau"];
function duplicar(c){
var x = Array();
x[0] = c[0]+c[0];
x[1] = c[1]+c[1];
return x;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método [.slice(0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) que irá criar uma nova array a partir da primeira sem alterar a primeira:

```js
var a = ["oi","tchau"];
function duplicar(c){
   var b = c.slice(0);
   b[0] = b[0]+b[0];
   b[1] = b[1]+b[1];
   b = b.join(" ")
   return b
}
console.log('Variável antes da função: "'+a+'"')
console.log('Retorno da função: "'+duplicar(a)+'"')
console.log('Variável após função: "'+a+'" (array inalterada)')
```